# REGEX - String must not start from these words and may contain alphanumeric characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, regex-lookarounds

Requirement are as follows:

```
1.First three characters must not be "CP ","C P". Note there is a space in both these words
2.First character may be alphanumeric, including À, Â, Ç, È
3.2nd and 3rd caracter can be any ascii character other than (0-31)
```

The part that I am having trouble with is how can I write regex where the string does not start with "CP " word or "C P" that word. Note that ASCII 32 is space character which is valid in regex match but not but in combination with "CP ".

I have tried something like this as starting point but to no avail

```
(?!CP )[^\x00-\x1F]
```

### **Sample Strings**

invalid text : CP 420, C P 420

Valid text: abc 420, 420 CP etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a starting anchor, you need to add the optional whitespace into the negative lookahead. It will be easier to list the characters you want than to list the characters you don't, since it is 2 different ranges. Try:

```
^(?!(?:C ?P|CP ?))[A-Za-z\dÀÂÇÈ][\x20-\xFF]{1,2}
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/4Rhv2V/2/

Comment: I have updated the demo with valid, invalid strings for testing. Can you please check. https://regex101.com/r/4Rhv2V/3. The requirement itself is not very clear, I admit.

Comment: I used those strings already, that is what lines 1 - 4 are. The `^` checks the start of the line (or string if the `m` modifier isn't present, I used it here to demonstrate). The blues are/would be matches.

Comment: Also the length can be any, restriction is on first 3 characters only. So J123456 will be a match. Also the match does not necessarily need to be from start of line. I am sorry I am not certain about some of the requirement myself as it was not well communicated with me.

Comment: How can it be `first 3 characters` if it isn't the `start of line`(/string)? The `{1,2}` is allowing 1 or 2 characters from the ascii range 32 - 255. `[A-Za-z\dÀÂÇÈ]` is allowing one alphanumerical character, included the specified accented characters. `^(?!(?:C ?P|CP ?))` is not `CP `, `C P`, or `CP`. The whole regex is from the start and doesn't care about anything after the first 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with some REGEX expressions, and arrived at this.

```
^((?!cp )(?!c p))(.)*$
```

This will yield following results

```
acp  -> Matched
cpa  -> Matched
fsdgsfdgsfd  -> Matched
c psadsadsadsa  -> Not Matched
cpasdsa  -> Matched
ac pasdsadsa  -> Matched
cp sadfsdfsdf  -> Not Matched
Ècp sadfsdfsdf  -> Matched
```

Not sure if this is what you will require. If not, please give more examples and I'll dig deeper.

**Edit 1**:
As per refined requirements, try if this works.

```
^((?!CP )(?!C P)(?!.[\x00-\x1F][\x00-\x1F]))(.)*$
```

Comment: I have updated sample string in question. I must admin the requirement is a bit gloomy to me.

Comment: Try this one. Updated again :D

Comment: The `(.)*` is too loose for the OPs requirements. `2nd and 3rd caracter can be any ascii character other than (0-31)`

Comment: Try with options /gm rather than /g. With /g it seems the app is counting the whole thing as one string, and thus failing..

Comment: Thank you @chris85 for pointing that out. Had forgotten to add condition for 3rd character. Added that. Now (.)* refers to any string that does not have either "CP ", "C P" or "(.)[x00-x1F][x00-x1F]".